# with quotation mark as my radio button value

Tags: html, c#-4.0

i have some values like

Ram's Home 
Sam's Home 
Dam's Home

i want to show them as radio button.

these values will be my text as well as value for the radio button

i want to create html string from c#

Please help me .. How to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

The following HTML shows how you can add radio buttons to your list.

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked />Ram's Home<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />Sam's Home<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other" />Dam's Home  
</form>
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.